# How to define and retrieve cookie value as array in CakePHP?

Tags: cakephp, cookies

How to define and retrieve cookie value as array in CakePHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to do anything special as Cake's CookieComponent handle's arrays seamlessly.

In your controller, make sure you've included the CookieComponent:

```
var $components = array('Cookie');
```

In your action, to write an array:

```
$this->Cookie->write('test', array('value1', 'value2'));
```

And then to read it back:

```
$test = $this->Cookie->read('test');  // $test will be an array
```

Comment: will the cookie look like CookieName[0] = value in browser's resources?